# Is It Possible To Load Add-in On Outlook Of MacOS

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have one native shim add-in project including C# class libraries.

Add-in works fine in windows OS (By using WIX).

Is it possible to load this add-in on outlook of MacOS?

If so, How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to load this add-in on outlook of MacOS?

No, it is not possible. There is no COM technology available on other platforms. COM add-ins can be run on Windows only.

> If so, How can i do that ?

There is no way to port an existing solution. You may consider developing a web-based Office add-in to support multiple platforms and devices. See [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) to get started quickly.